# compute contact mixing matrix from partnership degree data

Tags: infectious-diseases

In a discussion of sexual partnering, we are given the following information on a momentary degree distribution (as percentages):

```
degree    0       1       2      3
men      32.3    53.2    12.4    2.
women    26.7    71.9     1.1    0.2
```

From this, the authors construct a "proportional mixing model", treating the data as providing the marginal effects.  (The rounding error is small, so I'm going to ignore it.)  I want to understand what this means.  I'll try to get started.

To begin, since this is heterosexual mixing, there cannot be the same number of men and women participating, since men and women must be in the same number of partnerships.  So if there are say 10000 individuals, we must have about 4707 men and 5923 women. From this (and the above percentages) we know the number men and women of each degree, and thereby how many total partnerships (3954).

```
degree    0          1         2        3
men    1520.36    2504.12    583.67    94.1399
women  1413.23    3805.67     58.22    10.586
```

I think (?) the challenge is first to find the number of partnerships of each type.  Obviously there are no partnerships with individuals of degree 0, so we are looking to fill a 3 x 3 matrix of partnership counts, so that each deflated row sums to a male total and each deflated column sums to a female total (as given by the table).  (By deflated, I mean divided by the degree.)  This does not seem too bad on the face of it: 9 variables with 6 equations looks to leave solutions to spare.  But the system appears to be inconsistent.  So, I must misunderstand.

I get the impression that this is very standard stuff, but I'm not finding it in the textbook I have at hand.  I'm happy to work through the math if pointed to a careful discussion.